# Find first element in div that has margin? (purpose: remove margin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I need to find the first (and last) element in a div **that has a CSS margin** set (> 0 px). (important: this is not necessarily the first or last element!)

Basically, I need to do this so that I can remove the margin-top for the first element and the margin-bottom for the last. Now I know you'll probably say "why not use "p:last" CSS syntax?"

Because the first or last element can be something else as well, it could be a list (UL, OL), an image, a paragraph, etc.. I cannot simply do, ul:last, ol:last, p:last as that could result in multiple elements being matched (one per type).

I only want to apply this to a single element. So that's why I think jquery is the only solution. I would gladly be wrong on this though.

Comment: `:last` will never return more than one element at a time. Don't confuse it with `:last-of-type`. Perhaps you should show us your jQuery and HTML or a test case.

Comment: have you tried $('#d').children().filter(':last'), or (':first')?

Comment: @BoltClock said, :first,:last never return multiple elements, I think you meant that different element types might be returned?

Comment: @BoltClock - I know that :last only returns one element, the problem is that I do not know what element really has a margin and is last on the page. No sense doing p:last -> margin:0 when there's an UL below that with a margin.

Comment: OK I see what you mean. You should probably show your code, it's hard to figure out what you want by reading your description.

Comment: Well, I have no real code, I have tried some things but they didn't work. The div itself can have any possible content in there, so that's probably not worth sharing. (And that's the problem in itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want only the first/last child **with a margin**, I imagine you'll need to use jQuery/JavaScript:

```
var isfirst = 1, lastelm;
$("#divid").find("*").each(function() {
    var cur = $(this);
    if(parseInt(cur.css("margin-top")) > 0 && isfirst == 1) {
        cur.css("margin-top", 0);
        isfirst = 0;
    }
    if(parseInt(cur.css("margin-bottom")) > 0) {
        lastelm = cur;
    }
});
lastelm.css("margin-bottom", 0);
```

Comment: How can I get the children and the grandchildren and etc.. ? Because it could be a grandchild that has the first margin.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the filter method in jquery(http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Here is a sample i could think of

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>
        <p>A<p>        
        <p>B<p>        
        <p style="margin: 10px;">C<p>    
        <p style="margin: 10px;">C<p>     
        <p>D<p>        
      </p> 
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('p').filter(function(){
                return this.style.margin != '';
            }).last().css('color','red');             

         });

     </script>    
  <body>
```

​

You might want to build upon the filter logic...

Answer (score 0):

`:last` isn't actually a CSS selector outside of jQuery. But what you could use is `:first-child` as well as `:last-child`:

```
#my-element > *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#my-element > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Edit: Too late. However I'd definitely use the `>` selector so as not to style *every* first child in `#my-element` (like the first `li` in a `ul` or a `strong` inside a `p` etc).

Comment: The problem is that the first child may not have a margin, but only the second child. These are the unknowns.